# Download file with url as http://<site collection>/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=<doc id> using web request

Tags: sharepoint

I have a site collection in which Document Id feature is activated.
Documents are archived to this site collection from another site (in which Document Id is activated as well) and the only information I have about the moved file is the document id which is same between the source and the destination.
I need to download the file using web request, but my code gives '401 Unauthorised Exception'.
My code is as below:

```
string url = "http://<site collection>/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=<doc id>";
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;            
request.Method = "Get";            
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
var  credential= new NetworkCredential(username, password, domainname);
request.Credentials = credential;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I need to give some sort of authentication, but could not figure it out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards
Arjabh

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code inside of a

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
//code goes here
});
```

block

Comment: thanks for the reply but I am trying this code through a custom .Net application, not within the SharePoint.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to use the ClientContext class. It is meant to be used outside of the SharePoint environment and can query document libraries and return data. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.aspx for more info.

Comment: Cannot it be done using HttpWebRequest (the way browser downloads the file) since i need it to be a very light-weight app.

Comment: I'm not sure, I have never tried. At the very least you would have to login and authenticate somehow.